# GDM display manager fails to display login

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

When I boot my computer, I'm presented with a blank screen after the Ubuntu loading screen. The weird thing is that if I go into the [GRUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) loader, select recovery mode, but select to continue with normal boot, it works fine.

I tried reconfiguring as well as reinstalling [GDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Display_Manager). How can I fix it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While booting your Ubuntu machine, go to the console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and log in with your credentials and try installing [LightDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LightDM):

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

It will ask you which desktop manager you want to make the default. Select `lightdm` and proceed with the installation.

Log out and log back in the graphical mode by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>.

It should work fine this time. :)

Answer (score 7):

First press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, and log in into your account. Install [LightDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LightDM) as

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

Set LightDM as the default by writing

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Restart the system and voilà! Everything seems to be running perfectly!